# Rounding a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

How can I detect if a number is under the `0.5` and round it to `0.5`? For instance `2.34` to `2.5`, but then I have `2.51` should be `3.00`.

Comment: Can you post your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: function numberToHalf (n) {
   return Math.round(n + 0.5) - 0.5;
}

function routingNumber (n) {
   return Math.round(n);
}
Now I have to detect whether the number half part is more than 0.5 or less.The problem is how can I get the value of half part, for instance, 234.43 I need to now this .43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const halfRound = (num) => (Math.ceil(num) === Math.round(num)) ? Math.ceil(num) : (Math.ceil(num) - 0.5)

console.log(halfRound(2.34)); // 2.5
console.log(halfRound(2.51)); // 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Math.ceil() to round up the numbers.

Example: Math.ceil(2.51) = 3.

In order to round in decimal go to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

It has a very easy way for you to understand

Answer (score 0):

If your decimal part is bigger than 0.5 you can just use Math.round otherwise you need to add 0.5 to your float value.

```
const roundToHalf = function(value) {
    let decimal = (value - parseInt(value, 10)); //Decimal portion

    if (decimal > 0.5) {
        return Math.round(value);
    }

    return (parseInt(value, 10) + 0.5);
}

console.log(roundToHalf(0.5)); //0.5
console.log(roundToHalf(2.34)); //2.5
console.log(roundToHalf(2.51)); //3.0
```